# Qt for Desktop and Mobile application

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

This is the first time I need to make a program which runs on different platforms, i.e. Windows 10 , Android, iOS and maybe sometime later even on OS X.

I discovered **Qt** which seems to be the best solution for my problem. I have never used it before, so:

- Can I write the code as I would normally for a desktop application and then simply compile it for Windows, Android, iOS and OS X (I know I need XCode etc. for the Apple platforms but that is not the question) and it will run fine on any device?
- Can I make changes depending on the platform on which the program gets started? For example I want a blue background on Windows, but a red one on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to be aware of platform limitations, Qt limitations of some features available on some platforms, and of course, the specific features of each platform (i.e: the display size is very different so the overall experience change, etc).
2. Yes, you can check the current platform and make the changes according.
   There's a set of macros defined to identify the [platform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_AIX)
   AFAIK if you're using QML those macros are not available, but you can send them to QML using some C++ class and [integrating with QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html).